# How to see the full file name on the Lubuntu Desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, customization, desktop-environments, pcmanfm

If I have a file with several characters in it, only a certain number of initial characters is displayed on the Lubuntu desktop and Xfce desktops.

For example, I have a file titled, "interesting-links-on-default-browsers". It shows as "interesting-links-on-def..." with both DEs. However, single-clicking on the file in Xfce shows the full title but the truncated title remains in Lubuntu.

It's not a big deal, but if it's just a matter of setting something somewhere to get the full title visible on single-click, I'd be grateful for pointers.

Edit: Lubuntu 12.10
Edit on 20121020: For clarification, I'm meaning the icons on the desktop and not the "icon view" mode in the file manager (PCManFM).

Edit on 20121111:
See [bug #3586184](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3586184&group_id=156956&atid=801864).

Comment: I don't have experience with LXDE but you might check /home/user/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE/pcmanfm.conf

Comment: @Anthony, thank you for responding. I had looked at that file. On Lubuntu, it is in ~/.config/pcmanfm/lubuntu/. It has a section titled "desktop" but the entries there don't help this specific issue. My purpose in asking was mainly to know how to see the full title, **if** a way existed of which I was just ignorant. If there isn't a way, I don't mind at all.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the icon size... maybe? I remember reading that there is a way (in that file) to change the icon size AND the font type/size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature has been requested [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3586184&group_id=156956&atid=801864) and may become available in a future version of PCMan File Manager. Currently, there is no way to see the full file (or folder) name if it is lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

In default PCManFM in 1.0.0, the behavior was "Showing full filename in desktop and all windows opened in PCManFM".

***But, this has been patched by Ubuntu***. Ubuntu shows full filename in the all windows opened in PCManFM and shows truncated filename on the deskop. This was confirmed by lstranger [in here (sourceforge.net)](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3573172&group_id=156956&atid=801867). Ubuntu retained the older full filename in the PCManFM's windows

The [full filename is wrapped now in PCManFm 1.0.1](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3572974&group_id=156956&atid=801864).

This also is going to be changed in the latest release i.e 1.0.2.
In the latest version, it will show the filename according to the icon size also.So, if you have 54 sized icon, the file name will be longer. ([source](http://pcmanfm.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=pcmanfm/libfm;a=commit;h=9af4d83620fa3ddd93851f5c463ad12ca64b8fa6))
Also a tooltip will be shown for the full filename when hovered over them. ([source](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3572974&group_id=156956&atid=801864))

**Note, this behaviour is same for the windows opened in PCManFM's window and the desktop**

For recent changes in PCManFM, Have a look at [their blog](http://blog.lxde.org/?p=947).

#### Solution:

As a solution, I suggest you to get the PCManFM from the git repository and compile it yourself. In this way, You will at least get  the tooltip and bigger file name's with bigger icons. Good luck.

Comment: He is talking about files on the desktop - not on PCManFM - drop a long filename file on the desktop to see what happens